# Generate Running Hash (or Checksum) in C#?

Tags: c#, hash, checksum

Preface:

I am doing a data-import that has a verify-commit phase. The idea is that: the first phase allows taking data from various sources and then running various insert/update/validate operations on a database. The commit is rolled back but a "verification hash/checksum" is generated. The commit phase is the same, but, if the "verification hash/checksum" is the same then the operations will be committed. (The database will be running under the appropriate isolation levels.)

Restrictions:

- Input reading and operations are forward-read-once only
- Do not want to pre-create a stream (e.g. writing to MemoryStream not desirable) as there may be *a lot* of data. (It would work on our servers/load, but pretend memory is limited.)
- Do not want to "create my own". (I am aware of available code like [CRC-32 by Damien](http://damieng.com/blog/2006/08/08/calculating_crc32_in_c_and_net) which I could use/modify but would prefer something "standard".)

And what I (think I am) looking for:

A way to generate a Hash (e.g. SHA1 or MD5?) or a Checksum (e.g. CRC32 but hopefully more) based on input + operations. (The input/operations could themselves be hashed to values more fitting to the checksum generation but it would be nice just to be able to "write to steam".)

So, the question is:

**How to generate a Running Hash (or Checksum) in C#?**

Also, while there are CRC32 implementations that can be modified for a Running operation, what about running SHAx or MD5 hashes?

Am I missing some sort of handy Stream approach than could be used as an adapter?

(Critiques are welcome, but please also answer the above as applicable. Also, I would prefer not to deal with threads. ;-)

Comment: How can you run your import twice and at the same time read the input only once without buffering?

Comment: @usr I mean, "read once" per running. That is, no running a hash on the input stream first, for instance.

Comment: Ok and what properties does a "running hash" have for you?

Comment: @usr Preferably one that could use used as a Stream-like fashion (where I keep shoving in data and get a result after everything is written to it). The actual "strength" requirement is somewhat vague, though; CRC32 would likely be sufficient, but... that's not as interesting :-)

Comment: @pst, just for my own education, what is verify/commit thing used for (what problem does it solve)? Why do the same thing twice but commit only on the second run?

Comment: @zespri In my case it's because I let users (they are "administrators", but users to me) bulk-import data. The first step is like a "what if" and allows seeing records would be added/updated *along* with any data-warning message. Normally if this was just run synchronously there would just be a huge transaction/commit (and there is in the command-line version), but because this happens asynchronously (files upload/import run/log reviewed/commit), things can happen in-between - a different import, changing files, etc. The check is for "what you see" (wrt the logs) is "what you get".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hashes have a build and a finalization phase. You can shove arbitrary amounts of data in during the build phase. The data can be split up as you like. Finally, you finish the hash operation and get your hash.

You can use a writable [CryptoStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.cryptostream.aspx) to write your data. **This is the easiest way.**

Comment: The name sounds like it is going down the right track. Have a link to the documentation? (I'm already looking at it, but it's something an answer should have ;-)

Comment: @pst I think it is HashCore and HashFinal.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithm.hashcore(v=vs.90) and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.md5cryptoserviceprovider.hashfinal(v=vs.90)

Answer (score 9):

You can call [HashAlgorithm.TransformBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithm.transformblock%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) multiple times, and then calling `TransformFinalBlock` will give you the result of all blocks.

Chunk up your input (by reading x amount of bytes from a steam) and call `TransformBlock` with each chunk.

EDIT (from the msdn example):

```
public static void PrintHashMultiBlock(byte[] input, int size)
{
    SHA256Managed sha = new SHA256Managed();
    int offset = 0;

    while (input.Length - offset >= size)
        offset += sha.TransformBlock(input, offset, size, input, offset);

    sha.TransformFinalBlock(input, offset, input.Length - offset);
    Console.WriteLine("MultiBlock {0:00}: {1}", size, BytesToStr(sha.Hash));
}
```

Sorry I don't have any example readily available, though for you, you're basically replacing `input` with your own chunk, then the `size` would be the number of bytes in that chunk.  You will have to keep track of the offset yourself.

Comment: Could you post a code sample and explanation? I thought that was the way to go, but it's quite hard to understand how it works.

Comment: Thank you for the example, I can make sense of it now (+1).

Answer (score 2):

You can generate an MD5 hash using the [MD5CryptoServiceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.md5cryptoserviceprovider.aspx)'s [ComputeHash](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xa627k19.aspx) method.  It takes a stream as input.

Create a memory or file stream, write your hash inputs to that, and then call the ComputeHash method when you are done.

```
var myStream = new MemoryStream();

// Blah blah, write to the stream...

myStream.Position = 0;

using (var csp = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider()) {
    var myHash = csp.ComputeHash(myStream);
}
```

EDIT: One possibility to avoid building up massive Streams is calling this over and over in a loop and XORing the results:

```
// Assuming we had this somewhere:
Byte[] myRunningHash = new Byte[16];

// Later on, from above:
for (var i = 0; i < 16; i++) // I believe MD5 are 16-byte arrays.  Edit accordingly.
    myRunningHash[i] = myRunningHash[i] ^ [myHash[i];
```

EDIT #2: Finally, building on @usr's answer below, you can probably use HashCore and HashFinal:

```
using (var csp = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider()) {

    // My example here uses a foreach loop, but an 
    // event-driven stream-like approach is 
    // probably more what you are doing here.
    foreach (byte[] someData in myDataThings)
        csp.HashCore(someData, 0, someData.Length);

    var myHash = csp.HashFinal();
}
```

Comment: The problem is I don't want an intermediate (in-)memory stream (or extra materialized IO), unless I am failing at using Streams correctly...

Comment: If you have a stream already, just use that one.  Otherwise you are probably going to need an intermediate stream, since most real hashing algos use one as input.  If you have byte arrays, then use the TransformBlock method as per @Matthew's answer above.

Comment: I have an input stream that I consume from (forward read only). I don't have a[nother] stream to hand out, unfortunately. Also I need to be able to write the "operations" into the stream as knowing what would happen is important. I could use a MemoryStream, e.g. write to that, and then use as the feed to ComputeHash, but I'd like something that is a "running" computation without the intermediate data piling up.

Comment: @pst added example for HashCore and HashFinal, might be the best way.

Answer (score 0):

this is the canonical way:

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

public void CreateHash(string sSourceData)
{
    byte[] sourceBytes;
    byte[] hashBytes;

    //create Bytearray from source data
    sourceBytes = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sSourceData);

    // calculate 16 Byte Hashcode
    hashBytes = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider().ComputeHash(sourceBytes);
    string sOutput = ByteArrayToHexString(hashBytes);
 }

static string ByteArrayToHexString(byte[] arrInput)
{
    int i;
    StringBuilder sOutput = new StringBuilder(arrInput.Length);
    for (i = 0; i < arrInput.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        sOutput.Append(arrInput[i].ToString("X2"));
    }
    return sOutput.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have used this approach before, but it requires that all the data is present at time of the `ComputeHash` function call :(

Comment: okay, i see. any TransformBlock implementation will do then, MD5, SHA256, and so on.